# Observe mouseenter event after sometime

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, drop-down-menu

I have a jquery code for observing `mouseenter` event on menubar in a site.

```
menubar.on('mouseenter', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
       ... function body
});
```

Now I want to provide a delay such that the event function body executes after `2000 ms`, something like below:

```
menubar.on('mouseenter', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
    delay(2000);
    ... function body
});
```

I tried the following:

```
menubar.on('mouseenter', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
        delay(2000);
        ... function body
    });

var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

But still it doesn't consider the delay, just executes menu code instantly on `mouseenter`.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is a regular [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), which will delay the execution of any code you place inside it.

```
menubar.on('mouseenter', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // ... function body
    },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setTimeout`:

```
menubar.on('mouseenter', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Do the work here
    }, 2000);
});
```

You might want to cancel that if they leave the element before it fires:

```
var menubarMouseEnterTimerHandle = 0;
menubar
    .on('mouseenter', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
        clearTimeout(menubarMouseEnterTimerHandle); // Just in case, but we shouldn't get repeated mouseenters...
        menubarMouseEnterTimerHandle = setTimeout(function() {
            // Do the work here
        }, 2000);
    })
    .on('mouseleave', 'li.parent.level0', function() {
        clearTimeout(menubarMouseEnterTimerHandle);
        menubarMouseEnterTimerHandle = 0; 
    });
```

Note that `0` is an invalid timer handle, and `clearTimeout` will ignore a call made to it if the handle is `0`, so we don't need guards on the calls to `clearTimeout` above: